# when is a function changing by an order of 1,2,3...n

Tags: functions, mathematical-physics

say for example we have the distance traveled by a vehicle as a function of time.
if the speed(change in distance) is constant then this would be a linear function of order 1. 
if there was acceleration(change in (change in distance)) then this would be an order of 2. 
and if the acceleration itself was changing then this would be an order of 3.

my question is what would a function of order 4 be like? is it change in the change in acceleration and is it achievable in real life? also whats a function of order 1/2 be like?

Comment: There is no reason to believe that in real life the distance, velocity or acceleration actually follow particular polynomials.

Answer (score 2):

What you're talking about is the $n^{th}$ *derivative* of the position vector with respect to time.

The fourth derivative of position with respect to time is [jounce](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/1tvjhp/what_are_some_realworld_applications_of_jounce/).

As for the half derivative, you can read more about it [here](http://www.askamathematician.com/2015/05/q-is-there-such-a-thing-as-half-a-derivative/), but I don't think it has much physical significance like velocity, acceleration or jounce.